# SQL - Adding a count to select clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query to show a list of trending (most searched) names on my website:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS total_trends
FROM trending_names
WHERE dateTime BETWEEN '"&fromDate&"' AND '"&toDate&"' // -7 days to Now()
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

...and this is the kind of results I'm printing to screen:
(numbers represent quantity of searches made)

```
Angelina Jolie        31,293
Rihanna               26,722
Lindsay Lohan         18,351
Brad Pitt             11,901
```

I would now like to change the numbers to percentages; so I really need to be getting the total count of all trending names within the last 7 days, to calculate the correct percentage.

Is there a way I can add a total count to this query, without adding an additional query?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to use an additional query?

Comment: @JeremyS: Not really. I thought by adding it to this query it would perform better, rather than having two queries... I'm probably wrong though???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do in single query :

Try Below :

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS total_trends,
sum(if(dateTime BETWEEN '"&fromDate&"' AND '"&toDate&"' ,1,0)) as total_last_7_days,
((sum(if(dateTime BETWEEN '"&fromDate&"' AND '"&toDate&"' ,1,0)) /COUNT(*) ) *100)
as percentage                          // if you want to get only percentage
FROM trending_names
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery :

```
SELECT name, ((COUNT(*)*100)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM trending_names))  AS total_trends
FROM trending_names
WHERE dateTime BETWEEN '"&fromDate&"' AND '"&toDate&"' // -7 days to Now()
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Why are you grouping by name in your sub-select?

Comment: It's possible with without subquery. Avoid subquerires untll  no need for it

Answer (score 1):

I know you aren't running SQL Server, but some readers might be interested to see this  compact solution that's possible (SQL Server 2008 or later). I'm not sure many people know you can have a windowed aggregate that aggregates an aggregate.

```
select
  name,
  100.0*count(*)/sum(count(*)) over () as pct_trends
from trending_names
where dateTime between getdate()-7 and getdate()
group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so. You do need to compute that total count on a separate (sub)select

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,(total_trends*100.0/sum_total_trends) pct_trends
FROM
(
    SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS total_trends 
    FROM trending_names 
    WHERE dateTime BETWEEN '"&fromDate&"' AND '"&toDate&"' // -7 days to Now() 
    GROUP BY name 
    WITH ROLLUP
) A,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS sum_total_trends 
    FROM trending_names 
    WHERE dateTime BETWEEN '"&fromDate&"' AND '"&toDate&"' // -7 days to Now() 
) B;
```